# Shortcode call not working in WP Template

Tags: theme-development, shortcode, templates

I'm working with a Visual Composer shortcode to call a text resizer into being. When using the Visual Composer or the classic WYSIWYG, if I insert it's shortcode

```
[enlarge_text small='A' medium='A' large='A' default_value='medium']
```

into the editors it works with 0 issue. So in the interest of making my life easier, I went to add this into the Wordpress base templates with:

```
<?php
     echo do_shortcode('[enlarge_text small='A' medium='A' large='A' default_value='medium']');
?>
```

Sadly, no joy. I've checked to confirm the base templates are using the content callout, and should I edit them incorrectly they definitely take down the site, so I feel I'm in the right place instead of this theme having some special custom set hidden away that I'm just missing.

Thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: to answer this, you'll probably have to look at exactly what the shortcode does. there's probably some javascript and css that ties it all together which is missing and/or targeted incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the quotes:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[enlarge_text small="A" medium="A" large="A" default_value="medium"]'); ?>
```

Comment: You could be a bit more clear in your answer: OP has mixed up single and double quotes.

Comment: No need for clarity on Roman's part. He was right actually. The double quote did make the difference. All joy. 

Thank you Roman for something I obviously should have tried sooner. You da man.